# C# Forms application crashes after I re-open a secondary form

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio, winforms, fonts

I'm having this issue with my C# Forms application.
I loaded an Hebrew font into the app and I noticed it crashes the program when I re-open a form using a button.

```
InitializeComponent();
InitCustomLabelFont();


private void InitCustomLabelFont()
        {

            //Create your private font collection object
            PrivateFontCollection pfc = new PrivateFontCollection();

            //Select your font from the resources.
            int fontLength = Properties.Resources.SecularOne_Regular.Length;

            // create a buffer to read in to
            byte[] fontdata = Properties.Resources.SecularOne_Regular;

            // create an unsafe memory block for the font data
            System.IntPtr data = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(fontLength);

            // copy the bytes to the unsafe memory block
            Marshal.Copy(fontdata, 0, data, fontLength);

            // pass the font to the font collection
            pfc.AddMemoryFont(data, fontLength);

            // using the font...
            headerLbl.Font = new Font(pfc.Families[0], 20);
            loginBtn.Font = new Font(pfc.Families[0], 18);
            ...
            ...
        }
```

I have this InitCustomLabelFont() function on Form1 and Form2.
Form1 has a button that opens Form2. I noticed that when I re-open Form2 after I closed it I get a:

> System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected
> memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt

Does anyone has an idea why my app crashes?

*** EDIT ***

```
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1()); //this is where it crashes
        }

    }
```

Comment: That the full reproducing code?

Comment: *Upgrade* the `PrivateFontCollection` to a Field and call its `Dispose()` method when the Form that initialized it closes (`FormClosed` event). -- You could also create one in `Program.cs` for *general use* (handle `ThreadExit`)

Comment: In any case, it's important that you dispose of this object, at some point (depending on the setup) .

Comment: private void RegisterForm_FormClosing(Object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            Dispose();
        }

I added this and I still get crashes. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Is it possible that any of created resources may be global? In this case, both forms load that resource, one free the resource and the other have a corrupted reference to that resource. It's only something that came to my mind. In case it helps.

Comment: Are you calling `Dispose();` on what there? It looks like you're trying to dispose of the Form. You need to dispose of the `PrivateFontCollection` (declared as a Field). -- Anyway, nobody can see how these Forms are used, you mat have more than one issue.

Comment: I tried to Dispose() the PrivateFontCollection but unfortunately i get the same results

Comment: @BarShwartz Hi, if you find the solution to resolve the issue, you can add an answer instead of edit your question. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody it works now!

the thing was:

```
        private void RegisterForm_FormClosing(Object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) 
        {
            pfc.Dispose();
        }
```

while putting

```
private PrivateFontCollection pfc = new PrivateFontCollection();
```

above the `public Form1()`